# Cloudformation dependencies on shared resource

Tags: architecture, aws-cloudformation

**Situation**:

We have `Service A` and `Service B` that are deployed in the `same AWS account`. They both expect another stack with datalake D (Athena) to be deployed in this account.

Should the cloudformation template of Service A and Service B depend on the Datalake D? And if so, how would you do that? Or should they just assume it exists and only manage their downstream resources?

It feels you should reference it because if we move Service A to another account, one might forget this dependency. On the other hand, we don't want both Service A and B to deploy the stack since it is only needed once.

Comment: If everything is in one account and one region, you can export output from D, and import it in A and B stacks. Have you considered that?

Comment: No I haven't :) that would make A fail if the output of D does not exist? That would sound good. Care to provide an example as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that A, B and D are all stacks to be created in the **same region and account**, you could use [cross-stack references](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/walkthrough-crossstackref.html) to interlink D with A and B.

In this solution, the stack D would [export](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html) its outputs. For example:

```
Outputs:
  OutputFromD:
    Value: <a-value-to-be-exported>
    Export:
      Name: <export-name>
```

Then, where you need the `OutputFromD` in A and B, you would use [ImportValue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html). For example, in A and B:

```
Resources:

  SomeResource:
    Properties:
      SomeProperty: !ImportValue <export-name>
```

Comment: Thanks that looks perfect :) I'll try it tomorrow. Do you know the error it will raise when D is not deployed? (Nvm, ill add it to your post when I try it)